# How to install and use Lex on Cygwin?

Tags: installation, cygwin, flex-lexer, lex

I need to use Lex for my Compiler Design course but how do I install and use it on the Cygwin environment?

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to install Cygwin packages is the Cygwin `setup`.
https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html

`apt-cyg` is not supported, not maintained and prone to errors.

About Lex, you can find which package contains it using `cygcheck`

```
$ cygcheck -p bin/lex
Found 5 matches for bin/lex
flex-2.6.4-2 - flex: A fast lexical analyzer generator
...
```

so you need to install the `flex` package. With that you have:

```
$ cygcheck -l flex |grep bin
/usr/bin/flex++
/usr/bin/flex.exe
/usr/bin/lex
```

As additional info the last version of the C compiler is 10.2.0-1

```
$ cygcheck -p usr/bin/gcc
Found 10 matches for usr/bin/gcc
gcc-core-10.2.0-1 - gcc-core: GNU Compiler Collection (C, OpenMP)
gcc-core-7.4.0-1 - gcc-core: GNU Compiler Collection (C, OpenMP)
gcc-core-9.3.0-1 - gcc-core: GNU Compiler Collection (C, OpenMP)
gcc-core-9.3.0-2 - gcc-core: GNU Compiler Collection (C, OpenMP)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

First install the `apt-cyg` package manager from [here](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg). Then

```
apt-cyg install flex m4
```

Create a Lex file, say `sample.l`. Then,

```
lex sample.l
```

The output will be written to `lex.yy.c`. You can change this destination with `-o` flag in the previous command. Then, compile using

```
gcc lex.yy.c -lfl
```

**`fl`, as opposed to just `l`, is the linker argument**. The generated executable should be `a.exe` by default.
If you do not have `gcc`, then install it using

```
apt-cyg install gcc-core
```